# SparkSQL/JDBC error com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Column, parameter, or variable #7: Cannot find data type BLOB

Tags: scala, apache-spark, jdbc, apache-spark-sql, sql-server-2017

Saving DataFrame to table with `VARBINARY` columns is throwing error:

> com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Column, parameter, or
>   variable #7: Cannot find data type BLOB

If I try to use `VARBINARY` in `createTableColumnTypes` option, I get *"VARBINARY not supported"*.

Workaround is:

1. change TARGET schema to use `VARCHAR`.
2. Add `.option("createTableColumnTypes", "Col1 varchar(500), Col2) varchar(500)")`

While this workaround lets us go ahead with saving rest of data, actual binary data from source table (from where Data is read) is not saved correctly for these 2 columns - we see NULL data.

We are using MS SQL Server 2017 JDBC driver and Spark 2.3.2.

Any help, workaround to address this issue correctly so that we don't lose data is appreciated.

Comment: There is no "MS SQL Server 2017 JDBC driver". Exactly which version of the Microsoft SQL Server JDBC driver are you using? Also, please post a [mcve].

Comment: We are using 7.0 version that is marked as compatible with SQL Server 2017: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/microsoft-jdbc-driver-for-sql-server-support-matrix?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: Yes, but it is **not only** for SQL Server 2017... but still, we also need a [mcve].